# Check if object is instance of class with template

Tags: c++, class, templates, typechecking

My class:

```
template < typename T >
Array<T>{};
```

(Source data is stored in vector)

I have an object:

```
Array< string > a;
a.add("test");
```

And I have an object:

```
Array< Array< string > > b;
b.add(a);
```

How can I check:

1. Is `b[0]` an instance of `Array` (regardless of template type)?
2. Is `a[0]` an instance of any type except `Array`?

Comment: What do you mean by "check"? Clearly `b[0]` *is* such an "instance" in your code.

Comment: Except `Array` doesn't have an `operator[]`.

Comment: @KerrekSB typename of b[0] is Array<string>, typename of a[0] is string. I know it, but how I can check it via code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you can use C++11, creating your type traits; by example

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct Array
 { 
   std::vector<T> v;

   void add (T const t)
    { v.push_back(t); }
 };

template <typename>
struct isArray : public std::false_type
 { };

template <typename T>
struct isArray<Array<T>> : public std::true_type
 { };

template <typename T>
constexpr bool isArrayFunc (T const &)
 { return isArray<T>::value; }


int main()
 {
   Array<std::string> a;
   Array<Array<std::string>> b;

   a.add("test");
   b.add(a);

   std::cout << isArrayFunc(a.v[0]) << std::endl; // print 0
   std::cout << isArrayFunc(b.v[0]) << std::endl; // print 1
 }
```

If you can't use C++11 or newer but only C++98, you can simply write `isArray` as follows

```
template <typename>
struct isArray
 { static const bool value = false; };

template <typename T>
struct isArray< Array<T> >
 { static const bool value = true; };
```

and avoid the inclusion of `type_traits`

**--- EDIT ---**

Modified (transformed in `constexpr`) `isArrayFunc()`, as suggested by Kerrek SB (thanks!).

Comment: Checking this at runtime seem unusual. If you made `isArrayFunc` constexpr, it could be used in metaprogramming, which is where I'd expect the question to become relevant. (If it isn't for TMP, then I'd expect simple overloading to be more useful for whatever the OP wants to achieve.)

Comment: @KerrekSB - I suspect that, in metaprogramming, is the `struct isArray` that can be usefull but... why not; thanks.

Comment: @max66: I agree, it's mildly odd to check type traits on values, but why not. It might come up, and it might even be convenient somewhere. Maybe in a polymorphic lambda or some such.

Answer (score 4):

Below is a shorter version of the solution proposed by [max66](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41495065/4987285) that no longer uses struct `isArray`.
It works in C++98 and later revisions.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct Array
{ 
   std::vector<T> v;

   void add (T const t)
    { v.push_back(t); }
};

template <typename T>
constexpr bool isArrayFunc (T const &)
{ return false; }

template <typename T>
constexpr bool isArrayFunc (Array<T> const &)
{ return true; }

int main()
{
   Array<std::string> a;
   Array<Array<std::string>> b;

   a.add("test");
   b.add(a);

   std::cout << isArrayFunc(a.v[0]) << std::endl; // print 0
   std::cout << isArrayFunc(b.v[0]) << std::endl; // print 1
}
```

Answer (score -2):

in c++ you can use

```
if(typeid(obj1)==typeid(ob2))//or typeid(obj1)==classname
  cout <<"obj1 is instance of yourclassname"
```

in your case you can check that with  typeid(obj1)==std::array

Comment: the typeid is in <type_info> (standard lib)